# How can we re-size the attachmant file in salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, attachment

I am working on salesforce1 app where I have a apex:inputfile tag, on which I have added attribute capture, for capture image using mobile camera (capture=camera). This is working fine with both Android and iPhone. After capturing the image I need to attachment image to Account object. I am not able to save the image because the size of the attachment (blob file) is high. I am getting this error

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MAXIMUM_SIZE_OF_ATTACHMENT, attachment data exceeded maximum size: [BodyLength]
```

I know this is due to the size limit defined by the salesforce. So i want to resize the Attachment file before i insert. Is there any way to resize the Attachment before inserting. MY VF Page :

```
 <apex:page controller="imgUpload">
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#j_id0:j_id2:imgCss').attr('capture', 'camera');     });
```

```
 <STYLE>
       #j_id0:j_id2:imgCss{
        max-width: 50px;
        max-hight: 50px;
       } 
   </STYLE>
     <apex:form >

         <apex:commandButton action="{!displayImg}" value="Submit" />

             <apex:inputFile id="imgCss" accept="image/*" filename="{!fileName}" contentType="{!contentType}" value="{!photoUpload}" />

      </apex:form>
```

Controller :

```
public class imgUpload{

transient blob imgFile {get; set;}
public Blob photoUpload {get; set;}
public String contentType {get; set;}
public String fileName {get; set;}
public String attb {get; set;}

public imgUpload(){
    //SYSTEM.DEBUG('Image File ' + imgFile);
}

public string setattb(){
    return 'image/*" capture="camera';
}


public PageReference displayImg(){

    SYSTEM.DEBUG('Image File ' + imgFile);
    SYSTEM.DEBUG('file Name  ' + fileName );
    SYSTEM.DEBUG('Photo Upload ' + photoUpload);

    Attachment ac = new Attachment ();
    //SYSTEM.DEBUG('File size ' + photoUpload.fileSize());
    //photoUpload.fileSize() = photoUpload.fileSize()/2;
    ac.Body = photoUpload;
    ac.Name = fileName;
    ac.ParentId = '0019000000xRbBS';
    ac.ContentType=contentType ;
    try{
        insert ac;
        photoUpload = null;
        //imgFile
        //ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Inserted Successfully.');
        //ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Not bale to insert.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }

    return null;

}
}
```

Please guide me the best way to get the solution over this issue.